# How can I get identity of a disk?

Tags: c++, windows, identity, disk

I want to identify disk in c++ in my windows application.
For example:
I have a disk on E:\
Then I changed the disk, and replace it with another one. the name is still E:\
How can I know the disk is changed, it is not the original one?

If I have no administrator priority in win7, Can I still use some method to identy different disks?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the relevant methods are:

[`GetLogicalDrives()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364972(VS.85).aspx)

[`BOOL WINAPI GetVolumeInformation(
  __in_opt   LPCTSTR lpRootPathName,
  __out      LPTSTR lpVolumeNameBuffer,
  __in       DWORD nVolumeNameSize,
  __out_opt  LPDWORD lpVolumeSerialNumber,
  __out_opt  LPDWORD lpMaximumComponentLength,
  __out_opt  LPDWORD lpFileSystemFlags,
  __out      LPTSTR lpFileSystemNameBuffer,
  __in       DWORD nFileSystemNameSize
)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993(VS.85).aspx)

[`GetDriveType(string vol)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939(VS.85).aspx)

GetVolumeInformation will give you the serial number. If this isn't enough you will probably have to resort to [WMI_PhysicalMedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394346(v=VS.85).aspx). I believe all of this should work without Administrator privileges.

A page listing a bunch of relevant functions is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365730(v=VS.85).aspx