# Windows 7 & Java: Get Disk-identifier

Tags: java, windows, unique, disk, identifier

I have a hdd array with 4 encrypted hard-drives (truecrypt). I recently switched back from 5 years of linux to windows 7 and I find myself confronted with a problem I can't find a solution for.
Under linux there was a command called "fdisk" which gives you all running (not mounted!) harddrives plus a unique disk-identifier which doesn't change (something like: Disk Identifier: 00x33f1a3c1).
I need that same functionality under Windows, preferably writing the code in java.

cheers

edit:// For clarification, I need the Disk-ID without mounting the Disk!

Comment: I did write this code in jna. But am sure you can access the windows registry using java. The harddisk information is stored in windows registry, just forgotten the exact tree structure.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636314/how-can-i-get-identity-of-a-disk for API hints (but not: registry hive info).

Comment: @TheBlastOne thanks, but it seems as if this API-call works only for mounted drives. Unfortunately my drives are not mounted since they need to be decrypted with truecrypt first

Comment: I'm 99% sure you'll have to use the Windows Storage Management API, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830613(v=vs.85).aspx. To do it cleanly under all Windows variants, you'll also have to use APIs which are considered deprecated meanwhile, or will be someday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using VBS.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DiskUtils {
  private DiskUtils() {  }

  public static String getSerialNumber(String drive) {
  String result = "";
    try {
      File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto",".vbs");
      file.deleteOnExit();
      FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

      String vbs = "Set objFSO = CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\")\n"
                  +"Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives\n"
                  +"Set objDrive = colDrives.item(\"" + drive + "\")\n"
                  +"Wscript.Echo objDrive.SerialNumber";  
      fw.write(vbs);
      fw.close();
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
      BufferedReader input =
        new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line;
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
         result += line;
      }
      input.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.trim();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String sn = DiskUtils.getSerialNumber("C");
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((java.awt.Component)
         null, sn, "Serial Number of C:",
         javax.swing.JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this works only for mounted volumes. Like I said, the volumes are encrypted and need to be decrypted first (that's why I need the Disk-Identifier...)

Comment: The diskpart command-line utility may be useful then, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415/en-us . So you need to parse the output to extract the "Disk ID".